GCM Register API decommissioning in June 2024
In June 2023, I received an e-mail message from Firebase alreting me of deprecations that will affect may application.
The point that interests me the most is the deprecation and removal of the "Legacy HTTP API", used for sending notifications. I'm fixing that by updating to the a recent version of the Firebase Admin library for Java (version 9.2.0).



However, the e-mail also mentions the deprecation and removal of the GCM register API together with the GCM SDK, already deprecated since 2018. The alternative is to update the FCM Android SDK to to version 23.1.2.



(Sorry for posting pictures: I could not find the same document online)
Now, I'm puzzled about why I have to update the FCM SDK to version 23.1.2. My Android application already uses the FCM SDK version 17. If the problem is the GCM Register API, may I assume that any version of the FCM SDK does not use the GCM "Register API"? Or is that API still used in some way until version 23.1.2?
I suspect that the e-mail included that version because it was the most recent at the time the message was sent, in June 2023, but that there is no reason to update otherwise.
I know that staying on the last version would be the best thing to do in general, but this is a fairly old application that we are going to discontinue soon, so I would rather not spend time updating it.
Another problem is that I could not find any way to understand if my application is actually using the "GCM Register API". Is there a dashboard of some sort where I can find that out?

How to subscribe to depreciation notices / alerts? I just discovered that SDK is not working since June 2024
